# MySQL Fake Field as a Comment/Label/Placeholder

Tags: mysql

Can I create a "comment" of sorts within a Query?  i.e.

```
 SELECT ID, Title, Date, BlogPost AS Type FROM mytable;
```

In this case, BlogPost is not a column in my table, but a placeholder/comment.

So the query results would come back:

```
 ID      |       Title         |         Date        |        Type

 1               Cats             2014-09-28 00:00:00       BlogPost
 2             Kittens            2014-10-28 00:00:00       BlogPost
 3             Doggies            2014-11-28 00:00:00       BlogPost
```

So, to clarify, BlogPost is NOT coming from the table.  I want it to show up in the results via my query like a comment of sorts.

Comment: Do you need to add a column with just a static text field?

Comment: `'BlogPost' AS Type` you need single quote to wrap BlogPost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Select ID, Title, Date, 'BlogPost' AS Type FROM mytable;
```